# Noob tried to install Ubuntu, needs help

Tags: system-installation

I've decided to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and I'm trying to follow these  [instructions](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/).

After I'm done with the installation process, a window pops up that says I need to restart Ubuntu. I click on "restart now" (or something like this) and get a screen with the following:

```
[ 0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version 0xb2 (or later)

[ 1579.737040] reboot: Restarting system
```

And that's it. Nothing happens.

Sorry if this issue is easy to solve, I'm an inexperienced user and googling didn't get me anywhere.

**Edit:** the first error does not seem to be the problem, because it's not a fatal error which would prevent Ubuntu from booting

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because the first error is probably not the reason why ubuntu won't load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You should manually restart your system (using the hardware button or power cycle).

The first message, that TSC_DEADLINE is disabled, is a problem but not a fatal one.  It is not interfering with boot, reboot, or shutdown.  TSC is a "nice to have," not a "must have".  [See the good discussion of this error on the unix StackExchange.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410854/tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata)

Note that the instructions you followed assume some things about your computer (in particular, that it is a newish machine with a UEFI BIOS).  That's probably totally right for you, but if not you may have some trouble booting.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, [1579.737040] is a timestamp - the system had booted 1579 seconds before this line was printed. That's about 26 minutes...the time needed to install. Software reboot had apparently failed (we don't know why), time for a hardware reboot.

Answer (score 1):

start your system in non graphical mode or in recovery mode and install the microcode

For Intel

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode #(to install )
sudo apt-get upgrade intel-microcode #(to upgrade )
```

For AMD

```
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode #( to install )
sudo apt-get upgrade amd64-microcode #( to upgrade )
```

If this not help update your BIOS

Check your system by running command `iucode-tool --scan-system` ,  `sudo dmidecode -t bios -q` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'microcode'`  and post the result